# IIS: 404 error on every file in a virtual directory

Tags: iis-6, http-status-code-404

I am trying to write my first WCF service for IIS 6.0. I followed the instructions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx). I created the virtual directory, I can browse the directory fine but anything I click (even a sub-folder in that folder) gives me a 404 error.

What am I missing that I can not access any files or folders? Any logs or whatnot you need just tell me where to find them in the comments and I will post them.

UPDATE-
Found the log, here is what it says when I connect and try to click on a sub folder.

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2010-03-07 19:08:07
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status 
2010-03-07 19:08:07 W3SVC1 74.62.95.101 GET /prx2.php hash=AA70CBCE8DDD370B4A3E5F6500505C6FBA530220D856 80 - 221.192.199.35 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.0) 404 0 2
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2010-03-07 22:21:20
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status 
2010-03-07 22:21:20 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET /RemoteUserManagerService/ - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 401 2 2148074254
2010-03-07 22:21:26 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET /RemoteUserManagerService/ - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 401 1 0
2010-03-07 22:21:26 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET /RemoteUserManagerService/ - 80 webinfinity\srchamberlain 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 200 0 0
2010-03-07 22:21:29 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET /RemoteUserManagerService/bin/ - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 404 0 2
```

--Update again
I found this [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248033)

> IIS6 Dynamic Content: A 404.2 entry in the W3C Extended Log file is recorded when a Web Extension is not enabled. Use the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in to enable the appropriate Web extension. Default Web Extensions include: ASP, ASP.net, Server-Side Includes, WebDAV publishing, FrontPage Server Extensions, Common Gateway Interface (CGI). Custom extensions must be added and explicitly enabled. See the IIS 6.0 Help File for more information.

I am guessing the `404 0 2` at the end of the log is a 404.2 error. I now know the why, I still don't know the how on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS Manager on Windows 2003 under Web Sites I have Default Web Site and another Web Service Extensions. Double Click on the "Web Service Extensions" select .NET 4.0 and click the Allow button. Status should change from Prohibited to Allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Posting to myself to close the question. I ended up going with running it as a windows service instead of IIS. I could not get IIS to run.

---

EDIT: I am giving the other answer the accepted answer. I can not test this as this project has long past. But it make sense that it would be the correct answer.

Hoping someone would come by one day and give a real answer some day was the reason I just did not delete the question way back when I asked it.

Comment: I know you answered the question, but just for the record when looking at log files in the future, this wasn't a 404.2 error. It was a 404.0 error with a Win32 status of 2.